# Create and Assign a List of Generic Type to a property in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have a problem I can't solve after few days of researches...

I must create an application that read an Excel file and generate Objects depending on column's name and value for testing other applications. No trouble with that part, I can create and assign values to my object without knowing their type.

The problem I have is that some of these objects have relations between them, as Object A have a List(Of Object B). I can identify these.

My objects are declared like this:

```
Public Class Person
     Public Property Name as String
     Public Property Age as Integer
     Public Property Dogs as List(Of Dog)
     ...
End Class

Public Class Dog
     Public Property Name as String
     ...
End Class
```

When I debbug, I get something like that:
Person: Name = "Something", Age = 30, Dogs = Nothing

As my List(Of T) equals nothing, I need to instantiate it before adding object into it. As I haven't found any way yet to tell the List to instantiate itself, I tried to assign a New List to the property.

I have some code that I tried:

```
'In this case, unObjetParent would be a Person, and unObjetEnfant would be a Dog
Private Function AssocierObjets(ByRef unObjetParent As Object, ByRef unObjetEnfant As Object) As Boolean
    Dim proprietes() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = unObjetParent.GetType.GetProperties
    Dim typeEnfant As Type = unObjetEnfant.GetType

    For Each p As Reflection.PropertyInfo In proprietes
        If p.PropertyType.Name.Equals("List`1") Then
            Dim type As Type = p.PropertyType
            Dim splittedAssemblyQualifiedName As String() = type.AssemblyQualifiedName.Split(","c)
            Dim typeOfList As Type = type.GetType(splittedAssemblyQualifiedName(0).Substring(splittedAssemblyQualifiedName(0).LastIndexOf("["c) + 1))
            ' ^ The way I found to get the Type of the GenericArgument of the List before instantiating it.

            If typeOfList = typeEnfant Then

                'This create a object with it's name, in this case, it returns a Dog
                Dim prototype = DefinirObjet(typeOfList.Name)

                'My first try, it returns a List(Of VB$AnonymousType_0`1[System.Object])
                'which I can't convert into a List(Of Dog(for this example))
                Dim prop = New With {unObjetEnfant}
                Dim l = prop.CreateTypedList
                p.SetValue(unObjetParent, l, Nothing)

                'This one doesn't work either as it returns a List(Of Object)
                'which I can't convert into a List(Of Dog(for this example))
                p.SetValue(unObjetParent, CreateTypedList2(prototype), Nothing)

            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function CreateTypedList(Of T)(ByVal Prototype As T) As List(Of T)
    Return New List(Of T)()
End Function

Private Function CreateTypedList2(Of T)(ByVal unPrototype As T) As List(Of T)
    Return New List(Of T)
End Function
```

Also, I can't modify the objects, as I should be able to accept any library of object the we need to test.

Is this possible? I need to solve that problem. Thanks in advance

P.S.  Sorry if my english is bad, it's not my native language.

Comment: I don't understand why you need reflection here. Where is the code where you add _dogs_ to the `List(Of Dog)`? If the only problem is that the list is not initialized, why don't you initialize it? For example: `Public Property Dogs As New List(Of Dog)`

Comment: Well, as I said, I can't change the classes I work with, so I can't change Public property dogs as List(Of Dog) to public property dogs as NEW List(Of Dog). I use reflection to passe through all the properties of the object, as I don't know its type before runtime. I shall add the Dog to the list just before it(The list) get initialized.

Comment: after*  ... after the list get initialized, sorry

Comment: Sorry, but you’re definitely addressing the wrong problem here. You said you cannot change the objects but I don’t buy it. *Require* that they are properly constructed. I don’t believe that this isn’t true. At least not with the information you’ve given us. Your code is far from clean, and it’s horribly complex. The whole method can be replaced *with a single line* if you can simply enforce the single requirements that classes are properly constructible. This **must** be possible. I don’t see how it couldn’t.

Comment: I assure you I can't change how the object I work with are constructed, as what I'll receive is only a DLL from another team, my module is suppose to generate an entity with that for testing purpose. I know it's complex and/or horrible, I've been programming in VB.Net for only since March this year. If you know a way to instantiate a List of anything in an object that could also be anything, I would be glad to know, as I'd prefer a simplier solution than the one I came with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found a way to do what I needed:

```
      Dim t1 As Type = GetType(List(Of ))
      Dim constructed As Type = t1.MakeGenericType(typeEnfant)
      Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed)
```

This create an instance of a generic collection, in my case a List(Of T) of the specified type, and I'm able to asign it the the property I'm working on.